# SetTimeout function on a photoslide

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm creating a website on one page like a photoslide, here is my code and function on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EXfnN/24/)

There are two things I need help on.

1. `SetTimeout` on the second page, so if nobody clicks any buttons/a links for 5 seconds, it goes back to the first page automatically without any buttons/links being clicked.
2. On the third page, there is a 'thank you' a tag at the moment, I would like to remove that a tag entirely, so it is going to be an image on the page only. After 3 seconds it should goes back to the first page automatically.

How can I `setTimeout` on those two pages to be able to achieve the two functions above? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add this code to the beginning of the `a.panel` `click` event handler your timeouts will be in-effect:

```
//cache all the `a.panel` elements and setup a timer for our `setTimeout`s
var $panels = $('a.panel'),
    timer   = null;

//add click event handlers to all the `a.panel` links
$panels.click(function () {


    //clear our timer so we don't get redirected back to `#item1` after clicking a link in a timely manor
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = null;

    //cache the value of `$(this)` since we will use it more than once
    var $this = $(this);

    //check if we just clicked the link to the second page
    if ($this.attr('href') == '#item2') {

        //set a timer to return to the first page after five seconds of inactivity
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $panels.filter('[href="#item1"]').trigger('click');
        }, 5000);

    //check if we just clicked the link to the third page
    } else if ($this.attr('href') == '#item3') {

        //set a timer to return to the first page after three seconds of inactivity
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $panels.filter('[href="#item1"]').trigger('click');
        }, 3000);
    }
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/EXfnN/28/

Comment: Hi Jasper, thanks very much for your code, the second page is working like a charm, thanks. Just one question, my third page/div is an image, at this moment I have an a tag around it which I'd like to remove, is it possible to remove that a tag on the third item and the same function still works? Thank you!

Comment: @SamIAm One problem would be that clicking on the `a.panel` links is what resets the `timer` variable (stopping the auto-redirect functionality). So if there is no `a.panel` link to click on the third page then the user will be automatically taken back to the first page after three seconds. Another issue would be that my code uses that link (the one on the third page) to trigger the redirection to the first page. An easy work-around would be to change the link element to be hidden rather than get rid of it all together.

Comment: @SamIAm Here is a demo of my above comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/EXfnN/29/ (notice the `<a>` tag for the third page).

Comment: Thanks Jasper, you are super fast! With this auto-redirect functionality can I change three seconds to 5 seconds? Also can I change the moving speed? Thanks!

Comment: @SamIAm This will probably be my last comment for a while as I'll be away from my computer. You can alter the duration by changing the number of milliseconds that are passed into the `setTimeout` function, e.g. change `timer = setTimeout(..., 3000);` to `timer = setTimeout(..., 5000)`. `1000ms == 1 second`. Changing the "moving speed" is pretty much the same thing, just alter your `.scrollTo()` function call to have a longer duration (for slower, shorter duration for faster). Change: `$('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 800,` to: `$('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 1200,`.

Comment: @SamIAm Here is a demo of the above comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/EXfnN/30/